JBuilder and Rails 6.1
I am working on a POC for switching from active-model-serializer to jbuilder. I am very sad to see AMS being relegated to unsupported status. It's going to take forever to convert our 200+ serializers into jbuilder views.
My problem is that in my jbuilder view/serializer, I get an error saying:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `json' for an instance of User):

# controller
# GET /users_jbuilder/:event_id
def users_jbuilder
  @users = User.where(event: params[:event_id])
  render "users/index"
end

# /app/views/users/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @users do |user|
  json.id user.json.id
end

If I binding.pry into the serializer I have an instance of @users but I don't have access to json or json.array!.

according to the error message, the line in index.json.jbuilder should probably be json.id user.id. BTW if you are dependent on AMS, and it meets your needs, you might consider forking it and including it in your own repo as a gem.

Have you considered other alternatives to JBuilder? Blueprinter is an option if you can't go down the JSONAPI path.
